# How to change the View when i press an UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gridview, uibutton

I am new to iOS Development and Objective-C in general. Currently I am working on an app that contains 3 tabs. As you can see from the screenshot below the first tab contains a Table View with 2 cells.

[image: Table View]

So, after the user taps on one of the cells another detail view appears with buttons which later will be changed with pictures of the products that are going to be listed there.

[image: Detail View]

My question is: How do I connect the buttons with another view that will contain a table view with some details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Grid View to display your products. Use [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView). Its brilliant...

Comment: Since I'm new to all this, how exactly can i implement this GMGridView?

Comment: please follow the link - https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView. Its all there/...

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, hold down the control key and drag from your cell to the view controller you want to connect it to. Then set the segue style to "push." Set the name of your new segue. Then in code set the product data in the `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // GET THE SELECTED ROW
    NSInteger selectedRow = [[self.tableView indexPathForCell: sender] row];

    // PASS THE CORRESPONDING DATA TO THE NEXT VIEW CONTROLLER
    if (segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"MySegue") {
        MyViewController* myvc = (MyViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        MyProductData* selectedData = [_productData objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
        myvc.productData = selectedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So once the user taps a product image button, you want to display more detail about that item?

In your image grid view controller, just create a method:

```
- (IBAction)imageButtonAction:(id)sender {
    //  do something like check the [sender tag]
    //  to determine which button sent the message
    //  then instantiate the detail view controller and push
}
```

then connect this method to the Touch Up Inside action in Interface Builder.  Rather than a proliferation of action methods for each button, you could give each button a tag and route all of their Touch Up Inside actions to the same method.